# Is there a way to get rid of incessant password prompting for podcasts?

Tags: macos, podcasts, podcasts.app

[image: I get this trash prompt all the time]

how would I stop that?
I don't remember te fscking password

Comment: The Apple podcasts app (which I don't use, fyi, I use Overcast on iOS) *I believe* uses your iCloud/AppleID password. It is likely trying to log into the Apple Podcasts Directory.

Comment: You might be right, but I think I tried Apple ID password to no avail and now it's either somehow ceased and desisted or I'm currently on the wrong mac that does not exibit this irritant.